# Appium Java testNG Framework: driver cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, appium-android

I am creating my very first appium framework using testNG.

In the @before of this test class, I created my desired capabilities for an Appium android app.   I want to use the desired capabilities in the @test section of the class but I got the following error:

> driver cannot be resolved to a variable

So:

- How do I define 'driver'  @test level ?
- How would I define 'driver' even at  suite level ?

Here is the code:

```
public class TestDragnDrop {


    @BeforeTest
    public void DesiredCapabilities() throws MalformedURLException{



        DesiredCapabilities caps =new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "JacquelineNexus5");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.android.apis");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "ApiDemos");
        
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
        

    }


    @Test 
    //Scenario:  Perform Drag n drop function

    //Given I am on the Home screen 
    //When I  tap Views   
    //Then I will see the View menu 
    //When I am in the 'view menu' I will select 'drag n drop'
    //Then I will see 3 dots  
    //When  I select a dot and drag it
    //Then I will drop it on the dot below

    public void DragAndDrop(){

        TouchAction t = new TouchAction (driver);
        t.tap(driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Drag and Drop")).perform();

        t.longPress(driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_1")).
        moveTo(driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_3")).release().perform();


    }



}
```

Comment: I did find answer,  it  was to use private static AndroidDriver driver;   That does work and I did solve my initial problem.  HOWEVER, when I ran the test I got 'remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession'.  HOW DO I FIX THAT PROBLEM

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  I found the answer after a LOT of searching.

What you need to do is create your desired capabilities as shown above.

1. Then under public class add the following syntax

   static AndroidDriver driver;

This access modifier will allow you to access everything you created in the desired capabilities in EACH @test class.

2 . So you can do  `driver.findElementByClassName/id/Accessiblityid` etc as normal. Plus create additional test scenarios in testNG as normal.

updated code:

```
 public class TestDragnDrop {
 static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void DesiredCapabilities() throws MalformedURLException{



        DesiredCapabilities caps =new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "JacquelineNexus5");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.android.apis");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "ApiDemos");

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),caps);

    }

    @Test 
    //Scenario:  Perform Drag n drop function

    //Given I am on the Home screen 
    //When I  tap Views   
    //Then I will see the View menu 
    //When I am in the 'view menu' I will select 'drag n drop'
    //Then I will see 3 dots  
    //When  I select a dot and drag it
    //Then I will drop it on the dot below

    public void DragAndDrop(){

        driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Views").click();



        driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Drag and Drop")).click;

         TouchAction t = new TouchAction (driver);

        t.longPress(driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_1")).
        moveTo(driver.findElementById("io.appium.android.apis:id/drag_dot_3")).release().perform();
    }



}
```